# How do I connect MS access linked server on a network drive requiring a password

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, ms-access

I am trying to link an MS access mdb to my sql server 2005, the problem is that the MDB is located on a shared network drive which will require login/password.

How do I pass the username and password into the "Linked server Access MDB" template? I assume I have to @datsrc parameter?

Comment: Which is the source data? Is Access feeding SQL Server, or is Access linking tables to SQL Server's data?

Comment: The source data is MS Access and I'm linking it into SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than embedding credentials it would seem more sensible to use existing NT authentication and run the SQL Server service under an account which has access to the network drive.  See [question 63749](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749/) for some useful hints on service account setup.  So, either grant permission for the current SQL Server account to be able to access the network drive, or run the service under a different (possibly new) account which has access.