# SSIS/Integration Server Access Issue - No Local Admin rights

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, ssms, sql-server-2014

I am trying to find a solution to three issues I have encountered recently relating to SQL Server 2014. I am not an expert with this stuff by any means, but I've sort of fallen into needing to learn it in my current role. I went from never using SSMS a few months ago to (Trying) to teach myself how to use SSIS and SSRS. I've made a ton of progress, but now I'm stuck actually getting everything automated the way I want it.

The biggest challenge, and root of all my problems, stems from the fact that I am not a local admin on my machine. It was great to finally get IT to install the programs, but they do not want to give me, or anyone not in IT in my company, local admin access. Apart from asking my director to try to convince them to do so, I'm hoping for some solutions that would mean I don't have to call them every day to run these programs.

1. My integration server is running, I've got my SSIS packages built, but I can't connect to the Integration Server through SSMS, as I am not a local admin on my machine. I've read about going through dcomcnfg settings for REMOTE access issues, but I'm worried that won't help here since I'm trying to do this from the local machine and it still doesn't work. Any ideas as to how I can change the settings so that it runs for non-admin accounts or just make it work?
2. SSRS: I've built a report, and want to deploy it, but I don't have access to the reporting services configuration manager either. For whatever reason my reporting server is stopped in the server configuration manager. When I click on it, it says to use reporting services config mgr to tweak settings, so a bit stuck. Appears to be the same issue - not a local admin. Again, are there any settings I can change (getting IT to log in as an admin and walking them through what to change is my only choice, essentially).
3. SQL Server agent appears to be the same issue...

I could probably run my reports now, but it would be so much nicer to use these programs to the full extent. Any help would be appreciated here. I tried to research as much as possible, but most solutions seem to relate to logging on myself as an admin, running things as admin, etc, and I just can't do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to be local admin on your machine, SSIS and SSAS require Windows Authentication to log on remotely to the server via SSMS and publishing anything to the server from BIDS / SSDT Visual Studio Shell also requires WinAuth, though you can work locally and then swap the package to the server via Ctrl-C, and also instead of deploying SSRS you can login directly to the report manager and upload an RDL file (report). To start and stop SQL Agent services you need Windows Authentication via SSMS (in your setup), but to view the SQL Agent you must be in the SQL Server SysAdmin role (or at a grain level SQL Agent Reader via the MSDB rights.

I recommend you attempt to not get local administrator rights and instead ask 'merely' for rights to read and write to the server drives, and to manage only the aspects of SQL Server and it's services with a domain login on the server. You will require this anyway to check ingress and egress file locations and debug production issues (unless you have FTP to the box).

You do not have access to stop or start SQL Agent from your client SSMS also because I believe you are accessing it via SQL Authentication, which is not ideal or secure. But if you do not see the agent on the bottom left of SSMS it is because you do not have rights. If you see the Agent and it is red then the service is disabled and must be started.

You will need to get direct access to the SQL box (and you do not need local admin to manage SQL Server, just a domain account with some service rights and drive rights). If your system administrators are running SQL Server under Local Admin, then they should not be managing SQL Server in the first place (see my write up hyperlinked below).

The SSRS Team at Microsoft has merged into the SharePoint team, and SharePoint 2013 wraps up all of the BI tools right into it, so that is something you should also consider if you plan on building out a BI shop at your firm, i.e. you may not have to if you already have SharePoint installed.

Good luck, don't get discouraged.

[What user account would you recommend running the SQL Server Express 2008 services in a development environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749/what-user-account-would-you-recommend-running-the-sql-server-express-2008-servic)